# Showing data in array using angular

Tags: javascript, json, html, angularjs

I am trying to show data from an array but I don't know how to do it.

Here is a snippet fro my service.js file:

```
this.getdata = function() {
    var myData = $resource('url', {method: 'get', isArray: true});

    myData.prototype.destroy= function(callback) {
        return reffs.remove({id: this.id},callback);
    };

    return myData;
};
```

From the controller:

```
$scope.data = myservice.getdata().query;
alert($scope.data.length) // getting 4
alert($scope.data[1].id)  // getting undefined
alert($scope.data[1])     // getting undefined
```

I have also tried:

```
alert(JSON.parse($scope.data[1]).id)
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data[1]).id)
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data))
```

I got 4 for `alert(data.length)` but nothing else worked :( How do write them in an `alert` or html?

Comment: Open the Firebug or DevTool NETWORK console and chek what data returns with your Service.

Comment: What if you write `console.log($scope.data);`? In Firebug you can look at the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your resource like so:

```
var myData = $resource(
    'url/:id',                // url
    {id:'@id'},               // paramDefaults (optional)
    {'update':{method:'PUT'}} // actions (optional)
);
```

Notice the second and third argument. These are the `paramDefaults` and `actions`. In your code snippet, you attempted to override the default `get` behavior but didn't quite structure the argument properly. Regardless, this is not necessary, as `query` will do what you need. The only action you might want to add is an `update` action, as `ngResource` doesn't come with a default `PUT` action. You can read more about `ngResource` [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

Then you should be able to use your resource as follows:

```
$scope.data = myservice.getdata().query();
```

If you are still having trouble debugging, I would install [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en).